# MATLAB function syntax

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to learn [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) now; I tried a simple step, factorial function.

`factorial.m`:

```
function result = factorial (m)
    if m == 1
        result = m;
    else
       result = m .* factorial(m.-1);
    end
```

and then call it like this:

```
x = 2;
f = factorial (x)
```

but all I get is an error:

> Missing variable or function.

Comment: if m == 1 ; you forgot the ";"

Comment: @Radu Semi-colon is unnecessary here. Absence of it won't cause any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have a syntax error, in the second line there shouldn't be a `.` after the 2nd `m`
2. The `if` should be in a separate line from the function declaration.

Comment: what's the point of `.` exactly ?? I omitted it ,and it works !!

Comment: That's for element-wise operations between vectors. Since you operate on a single element in your function, you can omit it as well from the `*` operation.